# Two ajax-calls returned from same function - $(when) is this executed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I know there are several ways of executing code before an ajax-call is done and I understand that using when() - method is the recommended method of doing 
this. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

I have a function `loadFilter()` which returns an deferred object like this:

```
function loadFilter() {
    ...code...
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loadFile,
        data: {object: obj},
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $(targetDiv).html(data);
        initDrag(); 
        $("body").removeClass("wait");
    })
    .fail(function(ts) {
        alert(ts.responseText);
    });    
}
```

And the call from another function `getpage()` calls `loadFilter()` function twice with different values:

```
function getpage() {
    ...code...
    loadFilter(subcatId, "getnavigationpages", paginationDiv, doSearch);            
    loadFilter(subcatId, "getproducts", targetDiv, doSearch);   

    //When ajax-calls are done in function loadFilter. 
    $.when(loadFilter()).done(function(rsdata1) {
        ...code to execute when both loadFilter-functions above
    });
}
```

**How would I know when $.when() is executed???** I want to execute code when **both** `loadFilters()` are called, BUT I think!? $.when() can be executed
 either when first loadFilter() is called or second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) accepts an arbitrary number of promises and is resolved when *all* of those promises are resolved. So your code would look something like this:

```
$.when(
    loadFilter(subcatId, "getnavigationpages", paginationDiv, doSearch),
    loadFilter(subcatId, "getproducts", targetDiv, doSearch)
).always(function() {
    // Both have completed
});
```

I've used [`always`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) above, which is triggered regardless of the type of resolution (resolved, failed, etc.). Or you could use [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to just process only successful resolutions, or [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to handle each type of resolution separately.

Comment: Thank you for quick and good answer. Now I actually understand how to use then() as well :-) I will accept this an answer when I am able to (8 min left)

Comment: @TJCrowder: maybe you meant `always` instead of `then`. `always` is the "event" which gets triggered regardless of the deferred's state. `then` is used to chain deferreds, and it takes 3 arguments : `doneCallbacks, failCallbacks, progressCallbacks`. The